# pytest not read new test

Tags: python, pytest

I have a problem with pytest that doesn't run new test, but only the older test, even if I cut and paste old tests in a different folder.

the test, named test_city_function.py, is :

```
from city_function import pretty_city

def check_pretty_formatted_city_country():
    """are string rightly formatted?"""
    formatted_data = pretty_city ('milano', 'italia')
    assert formatted_data == 'Milano, Italia'`
```

When I ran pytest, pytest collected only an older test named "test_name_function.py".

```
 pytest
============================================ test session starts =============================================
platform linux -- Python 3.11.4, pytest-7.2.1, pluggy-1.0.0+repack
rootdir: /home/kko/Desktop/python_work
plugins: anyio-3.7.0
collected 2 items                                                                                            

test_name_function.py ..
```

Then I cut and copied "test_name_function.py" in a different folder(./Storico), but pytest collected again .Storico/test_name_function.py.

```
 pytest
============================================ test session starts =============================================
platform linux -- Python 3.11.4, pytest-7.2.1, pluggy-1.0.0+repack
rootdir: /home/kko/Desktop/python_work
plugins: anyio-3.7.0
collected 2 items                                                                                            

Storico/test_name_function.py
```

So I copied new test in a new folder and deleted older test and I ran again pytest in the new folder, but the result is :

```
pytest
=============================================== test session starts ===============================================
platform linux -- Python 3.11.4, pytest-7.2.1, pluggy-1.0.0+repack
rootdir: /home/kko/Desktop/python_work
plugins: anyio-3.7.0
collected 0 items
```

I try to run pytest --cache-clear, but nothing happens...

Any suggestions?

Comment: Pytest discovers tests based on the function name. Please rename `check_pretty_formatted_city_country ` to `test_pretty_formatted_city_country ` and retry.

Comment: @FiddleStix

It works, thanks... but I don't understand why pytest continues to run older test, even they are in another folders.

Comment: pytest will recursively search subdirectories during test discovery by default: https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/explanation/goodpractices.html#conventions-for-python-test-discovery